# A Better Way To Write If and If Else in Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm certain that this block of code can be compressed to something more simple and efficient. However, I'm stumped. If anyone could help me out then that would be extremely appreciated!

```
var close = "true";

$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle-nav]', function(event) {


  if ($(this) && close === "true") {
    console.log('close');
    $('#top').css('transform', 'rotate(45deg)').css('top', '10px');

    $('#mid').css('transform', 'rotate(-45deg)').css('top', '10px');

    $('#bot').css('display', 'none');
    close = "false";
  } 

  else if ($(this) && close === "false") {
     console.log('open');
    $('#top').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)').css('top', '0px');

    $('#mid').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)').css('top', '10px');

    $('#bot').css('display', 'block');

    close = "true";
  }

});
```

Comment: Why is `close` not a boolean?

Comment: Requests for code reviews should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Put all those css properties into classes and add and remove them from the elements with `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Comment: `$(this)` is always truthy, there's no point in putting it in an `if()` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `close` should really be a `boolean` value to make comparisons easier. However note that you can achieve what you require without the need for that variable at all by simply toggling the a CSS class on the required elements and the display state of `#bot`. Try this:

```
#top {
    top: 0;
}
#top.open { 
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 10px;  
}
#mid.open { 
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 10px; 
}
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle-nav]', function(event) {
    $('#top, #mid').toggleClass('open');
    $('#bot').toggle();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/0kjzzwco/)